# CollectionView with a GridItemsLayout and dynamic number of column

Tags: maui

I'm having a `CollectionView` with a `GridItemsLayout`. I want to change the number of columns based on the control size. This is what I have attempt:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiAppCollectionGridTest"
             x:Class="MauiAppCollectionGridTest.MainPage">

    <CollectionView x:Name="AlbumCollectionView">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout 
                    x:Name="AlbumViewLayout"
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Span="2"
                    VerticalItemSpacing="4"
                    HorizontalItemSpacing="4" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" HeightRequest="80">
                    <Label Text="{Binding }" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AlbumCollectionView.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList();

        SizeChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            int columns = 1 + (int) (Width / 100);

            AlbumCollectionView.ItemsLayout = new GridItemsLayout(columns, ItemsLayoutOrientation.Vertical);
        };
    }
}
```

The code runs correctly, but the layout is stuck on the original two columns:

[image: Layout with two columns]

I'm pretty sure this is a bug in the framework: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7747

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: Can Flexlayout work?

Comment: No, you cannot use a FlexLayout as an ItemsLayout in a CollectionView. But something like that would solve my problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Known bug](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7747).

Unfortunately, not yet scheduled to be fixed.

But hopefully it will get fixed indirectly, when other layout-related bugs are fixed.

Based on the symptom (of this, and other collection bugs), there appears to be information cached at "first layout", that does not get "re-calculated" in later layouts, even when it should.